# android RelativeLayout on 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout

I created simple UI and it works fine in Intellij Idea. 
But when I run it on HTC ONE X PLUS(android version 4.1.1) close button is showing wrong

here is image_elem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/example"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/close"
        android:id="@+id/closeImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_elem);
}
```

it shows in idea
[image]

and it shows on the device

[image: (http://joxi.ru/f6E7VIwyTJCTeU5Xj-o)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `android:layout_alignRight` - `Makes the right edge of this view match the right edge of the 
 given anchor view ID.`

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/close"
    android:id="@+id/closeImage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"/>
```

Comment: Why android:layout_alignRight? I mean, I have the same bug when using Xperia (4.1.2) but not when using Nexus 4 (5.0.0). Is there any bug in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_alignLeft`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/close"
    android:id="@+id/closeImage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"/>
```